Error When Starting Spring Boot Admin with Eureka: "Couldn't Retrieve Status for Instance"
I'm currently working with the following setup:

Spring Boot Version: 3.2.1
Spring Boot Admin Version: 3.2.1
Eureka Server for Service Discovery

When I attempt to start Spring Boot Admin, I encounter the following error in the console:

Couldn't retrieve status for Instance(id=32f1b3fba304, version=0, registration=Registration(name=GATEWAY, managementUrl=http://host:port/actuator, healthUrl=http://host:port/actuator/health, serviceUrl=http://host:port, source=discovery), registered=true, statusInfo=StatusInfo(status=UNKNOWN, details={}), statusTimestamp=2024-05-14T10:50:43.446449Z, info=Info(values={}), endpoints=Endpoints(endpoints={health=Endpoint(id=health, url=http://host:port/actuator/health)}), buildVersion=null, tags=Tags(values={}))

The application is configured to use Eureka for service discovery. Despite the error, the instance appears as UP in the Eureka dashboard, but Spring Boot Admin shows its status as UNKNOWN. I've confirmed the URLs provided in the registration are accessible.
What could be causing this issue and how can I fix it to correctly reflect the status in Spring Boot Admin? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Trying eureka server with Spring Boot admin

The things you already checked sound good. Have you tested accessibility of the urls from he host where admin server is running? Besides that you could compare with the demo here: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin-runtime-playground/tree/main/eureka
